# Submit form with JQuery and then load results from external page into DIV

Tags: jquery, forms, html, submit

I.

Using JQuery to submit to another page and load the results from the external page into the DIV. Can't seem to get this to work. Below is the code I'm using:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#msgform').submit(function () {
    $.post('blah.php', $('#msgform').serialize(), function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#msgresults').append(data);
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>

<form id="msgform" action="blah.php" method="post" style="padding:0px;margin:0px;">
<input type="hidden" name="strmemid" value="someid" />
<textarea name="message" id="msgtextarea"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<div id="msgresults"></div>
```

II.

OK. I'm using the JQuery form plugin and got the page and database update to work. All I need now is to replace the alert("Thank you for your comment") with something that updates or appends the response from the external page after form submission to the 'msgresults' DIV. TIA

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.form.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
$('#msgform').ajaxForm(function() { 
alert("Thank you for your comment!"); 
}); 
}); 
</script>

<div id="msgresults"></div>
```

III.

Finally this code works

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#msgform').ajaxForm(function (data, textStatus) {
         $('#msgresults').append(data);
    });
}); 
</script>
```

Comment: What exactly happens when you say this doesn't work? Does your external source return data properly, for instance?

Comment: Try your code in Firefox+Firebug. You'll be able to see in the console when the request is made, what HTTP code is returned (200, 500, etc.), and even drill-down into the response.

Comment: where exactly you are getting the error

Comment: i'm using classic ASP and included the JQuery in the external page also. Nothing is returned to the DIV and nothing is updated in the database.

Comment: Using the JQuery Form plugin solved one problem. I can update the database now but still a little foggy on appending the response from the page submitted to, to the 'msgresults' DIV. Any help appreciated. TIA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of things that could be going wrong.  Are you sure the AJAX request is successfully returned?  I would suggest switching to

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: 'blah.php',
  data: $('#msgform').serialize(),
  success: function (data, textStatus) {
     alert(data, textStatus);
     $('#msgresults').append(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr, status, e) {
    alert(status, e);
  }
});
```

It'll help you debug the ajax portion of your code.  $.post doesn't handle errors, so (in my opinion) it's pretty much never a good idea to use because you could always have network errors that need handling.  With newer jQuery you still have the .error() method on the xhr though, so I suppose that's an alternative.

Comment: I received an Error alert. Hmm

Comment: Cool, so depending on what the error is, you can start debugging from there.

Comment: Using the JQuery Form plugin solved one problem. I can update the database now but still a little foggy on appending the response from the page submitted to, to the 'msgresults' DIV. Any help appreciated. TIA.

Comment: .ajaxForm(function(data) { $('#msgresults').append(data); }); should work